# Background Package with Options

Tags: packages, backgrounds

I get the error message `Error: Unknown option pages=some for package background`, when I tried to compile the following code from the manual of the Background package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pages=some,placement=top]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\backgroundsetup{contents=A,color=yellow}
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\backgroundsetup{contents=B,color=blue}
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works fine for me with the latest TeXLive2012. What version are you using? I'd recommend updating to the latest release. And I confirmed that I get the same error message as you with TeXLive 2011.

Comment: The manual and your example have the key as `pages`, your error has `page`. Which did you use and what version of `background` do you have installed?

Comment: @JosephWright: I googled and found the following manual of version 1. (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/background/background.pdf)

Comment: @PeterGrill: I have TeXLive2012.  That is strange.

Comment: @Sony the reason is that when TeX Live2012 was made public, it shipped version 1.1 of `background`; only two months after (or so) I uploaded version 2.0 to CTAN. So if you haven't updated your TeX Live2012 installation after September 2012, it will still contain version 1.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the newest version (2.0) of the package, the code you posted produces no errors; with older versions you will get the error mentioned, so it seems that you are using an outdated version.

In older versions, instead of

```
\usepackage[pages=some,placement=top]{background}
```

you have to use

```
\usepackage[some,top]{background}
```

additionally, `\backgroundsetup` is not available in older versions so you will have to use the older user interface described in Section **4
Compatibility with version 1.0** of the documentation, and write something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[some,top]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\SetBgContents{A}
\SetBgColor{yellow}
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\SetBgContents{B}
\SetBgColor{blue}
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Version 2.0 (the current one) has a better user interface and some additional features, so I recommend updating the package.

Comment: I checked with TeXLiveUtility and it says that the background package is installed.  But, according to README it is the version 1.  How can I get the version 2?

Comment: @Sony in TeX Live you can use the package manager; once an appropriate repository has been enabled, run in a terminal `tlmgr update --self --all` (this will update your LaTeX system) or simply `tlmgr update background` (this will update only the package). Another option is to install the package manually; there are some answers in this site explaining how to do this (basically, run `latex` on the file `background.ins` ([`available here`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/background)) and move the generated file `background.sty` somewhere TeX can find it.)