# LaTeX Error: Unknown option `some' for package `background'

Tags: pdftex, xetex, luatex

I have a LaTeX file. It builds fine on Linux and Windows. It also has built on a Mac.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{scale=1}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Now, on my machine, a build grumbles on this:

```
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
```

Output:  `LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'pages=some' for package 'background'.`

[There was a suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98518/293040) to try doing it like this:

```
\usepackage[some]{background}
```

I've [checked the documentation](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/background/background.pdf), and the option is there.
If I remove the option, (`\usepackage{background}`), then it can't recognize this:

```
\backgroundsetup{...}
```

Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \backgroundsetup
                  {
```

LaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX the same problem.

How do I launch the build?

---

**Here's the full log:**

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (MiKTeX 22.1) (format=lualatex 2023.11.9)  14 DEC 2023 10:04
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-01>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/mykola/Library/Application S
upport/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-08-19.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/luatex/luaotf
load/fontloader-2023-08-19.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.133
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/mykola/Library/Application S
upport/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. ("/Library/Application 
Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /Users/mykola/Library/Applicat
ion Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.g
z)
\c@part=\count184
\c@section=\count185
\c@subsection=\count186
\c@subsubsection=\count187
\c@paragraph=\count188
\c@subparagraph=\count189
\c@figure=\count190
\c@table=\count191
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
("/Users/mykola/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ppo
wer4/background.sty"

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `pages=some' for package `background'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31 
   
? 

("/Users/mykola/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ppo
wer4/pause.sty"
("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/color.s
ty"
Package: color 2022/01/06 v1.3d Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/col
or.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 149.

("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics-def/lua
tex.def"
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/mathcol
or.ltx"))))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \backgroundsetup 
                 
l.3 \backgroundsetup
                  {scale=1}
? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \backgroundsetup{s
                    cale=1}
? 

("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/l3backend/l3back
end-luatex.def"
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-10-23 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count192
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.

("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

("/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/context/base/mkii/supp
-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count193
\scratchdimen=\dimen140
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count194
\nofMParguments=\count195
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count196
\MPscratchDim=\dimen141
\MPnumerator=\count197
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count198
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) [1

{/Users/mykola/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/fonts/map/pdftex/p
dftex.map}] (./test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-01>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1141 strings out of 476612
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:38,3:6,4:8,5:22,6:4,7:64,9:28
 23131 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 72i,5n,65p,242b,126s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmr
oman10-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 3794 bytes).

PDF statistics: 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: as always on this site please don't post sniplets like this. Please post full but minimal examples that others can copy and test on their system as is.

Comment: The documentation recommends to use pages=some instead …

Comment: There is no option `some` in the doc.

Comment: It will not build fine on Windows, you will get the same error in all cases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, [pages=some] has no effect. I've added the link to a suggestion about [some]. Anyways, [pages=some] won't work.

Comment: @daleif I've added the minimum reproducible example. Please try. On my machine this test snippet fails as well.

Comment: your example runs without error in texlive, show your full log, you probably have a local version of background.cls

Comment: Compiles without issues on my TeXLive.

Comment: I tried with all TeX Live versions I have on my machine, that is, from 2012 to 2023 and no run gave the error. Check what `background.sty` file is loaded on the machine where you get the error and you'll see that you have a spurious one.

Comment: Note that the answer you link is from 2013 and to refers to "old versions" so ten years later you would have to have a truly ancient version for the `some` option.

Comment: @MykolaTetiuk, when you write "Now, on my machine ..." how does it differ from the ones which work fine to your words with Linux, Windows, Mac? How actual are all your Latex-relevant installations "on your machine"?

Comment: @MS-SPO No idea. I've got the latest version of the `background` package, -- admin and user -- in MikTeX. Still, it won't work at all. My solution was to comment out the page this is used and the package include and then to remember to uncomment that back.

Comment: So do as @DavidCarlisle asked and provide the full log when you try to compile the minimal example included in your question. Just because MikTeX says you have the latest version doesn't mean you don't have another spurious one somewhere. Your log will tell us where.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle full log added. I pressed enter to skip problems to let it build till the end.

Comment: you are using ppower4/background.sty  but following documentation from background/background.sty which is a completely different package

Comment: " I pressed enter to skip problems to let it build till the end." that is OK for debugging but any pdf generated after an error is not intended to be usable and if asking here always ask about the _first_ error, showing the exact message from the log file.  If you scroll past an error you may get further errors or may get pdf output but they are quite likely spurious artifacts of tex trying to recover from the first error.

Comment: luatex 1.14 seems quite old, is that really what you get in an up to date miktex? (texlive 2023 has luatex 1.17.0)